# Filter Zabbix Tags in Grafana Dashboard

Tags: grafana, dashboard, zabbix, grafana-variable

I have a Dashboard in Grafana and I added a Dashboard with Zabbix Problems
I'm monitoring a Switch with multiple interfaces.
In the 'tags' field inside the Grafana panel, what should I put to display only all items that contain the tag 'Interface: Gigabitxxx'
Since there are more than 20 Gigabit interfaces.

I tried these possibilities in the 'tags' field
[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any idea if it is possible to perform this filter or is there another way?

Comment: looks like regular expressions are not supported in the Tags field of the plugin